# Laravel 6: Get console parameter options outside a command class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want to be able to get the console argument outside of a console command class in Laravel 6.

In a command class you would usually do this:

```
$this->argument('tenant');
```

However, this, of course, only works if the class you're in extends `Command`.

The way I have gone around this issue is as follows:

```php
if (App::runningInConsole()) {
    $input = new ArgvInput();
    $tenant = $input->getParameterOption('--tenant');
    if ($tenant !== null && $tenant !== false) {
        $tenant = ltrim($tenant, '='); // remove first equals
    }
}
```

However, it seems like a hacky way of achieving this. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Where is that `if` block? Inside another class? Why not pass the argument in that class's constructor?

Comment: It's in the `AppServiceProvider`, so can't be passed as an parameter

Comment: It would be `$this->option('tenant');` if you are later trying to fetch it using `--tenant`.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect to pass a value with the option like `--tenant={id}` then you can do:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

$tenant = (new ArgvInput())->getParameterOption('--tenant');
```

If you expect the option like behave as a flag like `--force` then you can do:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

$force = (new ArgvInput())->hasParameterOption('--force');
```